# Execute PostgreSQL function with LATIN1 client encoding in JPA

Tags: postgresql, function, jpa, character-encoding

I have a function in a PostgreSQL database that search a plain txt file in server and process the data inside the file. The SQL function changes the client encoding to `LATIN1` due to the uploaded file format (`SET client_encoding ='LATIN1';`). When I execute the function locally (with PgAdmin), it works, but when I execute the function with JPA Native Query, I get this error:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server's client_encoding parameter was changed to LATIN1. The JDBC driver requires client_encoding to be UTF8 for correct operation.
```

This is my JPA function:

```
public boolean importFile() {
    boolean res = false;

    try {
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
        getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT import()").executeUpdate();
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        res = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return res;
}
```

If matters, I'm using EclipseLink(JPA 2.1), JSF 2.2 (PrimeFaces 6.1), PostgreSQL 9.5.8.

Comment: try `SET LOCAL client_encoding ='LATIN1';` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the `client_encoding` setting for the duration of a function call without affecting the session state, you can attach a `SET` clause to the function itself:

```
CREATE FUNCTION import() RETURNS void
SET client_encoding = 'LATIN1'
AS ...
```

Though if your function is loading the file via `COPY`, there's no need to change your `client_encoding` setting; you can specify the file encoding in the `COPY` command itself:

```
COPY my_table
FROM '/path/to/my_file'
ENCODING 'LATIN1'
```